# Parse Error JSON.Parse when using getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

It's my 1st time coding with JS & JSON & I've a error message when I used getJSON :

> parsererror
>
> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data
>
> return window.JSON.parse( data );

Here my code :

```
$.getJSON("../processeur.php",{
    idProg: idp,
    exercice: exo,
    ajax: "true"})
    .done(
    function(response)
    {
    // alert( "success" );

        var options ="";
        if(response != null)
        {
            var length = response.data.length;
            for(var i=0; i<length; i++)
            {
                options +="<option value = '"+response.data[i]+"'>"+response.data[i];"</option>";
            }
        }


        $("#Liberation tbody").append
        (
            "<tr>"+            
                "<td align='center'><input class='liberationL' name='liberationL' type='text'/></td>"+
                "<td align='center'><input class='serviceL' name='serviceL' type='text'/></td>"+
                //liste déroulante des codes projets destinataires
                "<td align='center'>"+"<select class='codest' name ='codest' id=listecodes >"+"<option>Aucun</option>"+options+"</select>"+"</td>"+
//                "<td align='center'><input class='dateL' name='dateL' type='text'/><span><br>jj-mm-AAAA</span></td>"+
        "<td align='center'><input type='text' class='dateL' id='DateF' name='dateL' onclick='javascript:onCalendar_click();'/></td>"+
                "<td align='center'><input class='montantL' name='montantL' type='text'/></td>"+           
                //liste déroulante des types de mouvements            
                "<td align='center'>"+"<select class='mouvementL' name='mouvementL'>"+"<option value='lc'>LC(-)</option>"+"<option value='vc'>VC(+)</option>"+"<option value='ci'>CI</option>"+"</select>"+"</td>"+
                "<td align='center'>"+
                "<img src='../images/enregistrer.png' class='btnEnregistrerLiberation'"+"style='cursor: pointer;'/>"+' '+"<img src='../images/supprimer.png' class='btnSuppLiberation'"+"style='cursor: pointer;'/>"+"</td>"+
            "</tr>");
            $(".btnEnregistrerLiberation").bind("click",EnregistrerLiberation); 
            $(".btnSuppLiberation").bind("click",SupprimerLib);

    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, err){
        alert( "error : " + textStatus );
        console.log( textStatus, err );
    });
```

Here my php code :

```
include './BD/T_mouvements.php';
include '../sql.php';
require './jsonwrapper/jsonwrapper.php';

$idProg = $_GET['idProg']; 
$exercice = $_GET['exercice'];

$array = array();
$liste = selectionnerListePro($exercice, $idProg);
//$liste = selectionnerListePro(2011, 4);

foreach ($liste as $item) 
{     
    $array[] = array($item);  
}
echo "{\"data\":". json_encode($array) . "}";
exit();
```

And here the result of my php code when parameters are choose manually for function which runs query (for exemple 2011 & 4) :

```
{"data":[["DEV-SID"],["ENTREPOTDUI"],["HYDROGEOL"],["MES-TEMPS"],["MET-ENTREPO"],["MIG-BO\/XI"],["SID-AMODG"],["SID-ARCHID"],["SID-DSI"],["SID-FNGE"],["SID-OT-POL"],["SID-PILOTAG"],["SID-USAGRH"],["SIG-3D"],["SIG-ALTERNA"],["SIG-BDTOPO"],["SIG-CAO-DAO"],["SIG-DON-PDI"],["SIG-DONNEES"],["SIG-ORTHO"],["SIG-PLATGEO"],["SIG-STRUCTU"],["SIG-TOURNEE"],["SIG-WEB-PDI"],["STAT-CREDOC"]]}
```

I don't understand where is my bug..

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/ - the JSON is not valid - also your paste has a hidden char in front of the data - The valid object could look like `{"data":["DEV-SID","ENTREPOTDUI","HYDROGEOL","MES-TEMPS","MET-ENTREPO","MIG-BO\/XI","SID-AMODG","SID-ARCHID","SID-DSI","SID-FNGE","SID-OT-POL","SID-PILOTAG","SID-USAGRH","SIG-3D","SIG-ALTERNA","SIG-BDTOPO","SIG-CAO-DAO","SIG-DON-PDI","SIG-DONNEES","SIG-ORTHO","SIG-PLATGEO","SIG-STRUCTU","SIG-TOURNEE","SIG-WEB-PDI","STAT-CREDOC"]
}`

Comment: Why ? Where I did a mistake ?

Comment: You might want to use `json_encode` for the entire result. Something like `echo json_encode(['data' => $array]);`

Comment: I don't understand why my JSON is not valide. I follow the API [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

I tried to encode the entire result but it semms to change nothing :s

Comment: Do you save your PHP source code as UTF-8 with BOM?

Comment: @mplungjan there is no hidden char.
Here my echo ==> 'echo json_encode(['data' => $array]);'

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I don't think so. I use Netbeans with default config

Comment: Although you can't see the char it is there, trust us. Use a JSON validator online, generally the show the hidden char and if your JSON is malformed! Try http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: RiggsFolly helped me to get a better result without this hidden char :) 
But still get error with getJSON :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do this with AJAX, & it finally works !! Here my code :

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
    url: "../processeur.php",
    dataType: "json",
        data: dataString,
    success: function(response)
        {
          //alert("success");

            var options ="";

            if(response != null)
            {

                for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++)
                {
                    options +="<option value = '"+response.data[i]+"'>"+response.data[i];"</option>";
                }
            }


            $("#Liberation tbody").append
            (
                "<tr>"+            
                    "<td align='center'><input class='liberationL' name='liberationL' type='text'/></td>"+
                    "<td align='center'><input class='serviceL' name='serviceL' type='text'/></td>"+
                    //liste déroulante des codes projets destinataires
                    "<td align='center'>"+"<select class='codest' name ='codest' id=listecodes >"+"<option>Aucun</option>"+options+"</select>"+"</td>"+
    //                "<td align='center'><input class='dateL' name='dateL' type='text'/><span><br>jj-mm-AAAA</span></td>"+
            "<td align='center'><input type='text' class='dateL' id='DateF' name='dateL' onclick='javascript:onCalendar_click();'/></td>"+
                    "<td align='center'><input class='montantL' name='montantL' type='text'/></td>"+           
                    //liste déroulante des types de mouvements            
                    "<td align='center'>"+"<select class='mouvementL' name='mouvementL'>"+"<option value='lc'>LC(-)</option>"+"<option value='vc'>VC(+)</option>"+"<option value='ci'>CI</option>"+"</select>"+"</td>"+
                    "<td align='center'>"+
                    "<img src='../images/enregistrer.png' class='btnEnregistrerLiberation'"+"style='cursor: pointer;'/>"+' '+"<img src='../images/supprimer.png' class='btnSuppLiberation'"+"style='cursor: pointer;'/>"+"</td>"+
                "</tr>");
                $(".btnEnregistrerLiberation").bind("click",EnregistrerLiberation); 
                $(".btnSuppLiberation").bind("click",SupprimerLib);
        },
        error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, err){
        alert( "error : " + textStatus );
        console.log( textStatus, err );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `json_encode()` function will do everything for you. Just create the data structure you want as an array or an object and the leave `json_encode()` to do all the hard work.

So change `echo "{\"data\":". json_encode($array) . "}";` to

```
echo json_encode( array('data'=>$array) );
```

I am also fairly sure you can remove some unnecessary code from your script. You seem to be getting an array of arrays back from `selectionnerListePro()` and then processing that array of arrays into another array of arrays, but making no modifications in the process.

So this

```
$liste = selectionnerListePro($exercice, $idProg);
//$liste = selectionnerListePro(2011, 4);

foreach ($liste as $item) 
{     
    $array[] = array($item);  
}
echo json_encode( array('data'=>$array) );
```

Could be reduced to

```
$liste = selectionnerListePro($exercice, $idProg);
echo json_encode( array('data'=>$liste) );
```

Comment: Thanks the result is more "clean" : {"data":["DEV-SID","ENTREPOTDUI","HYDROGEOL","MES-TEMPS","MET-ENTREPO","MIG-BO\/XI","SID-AMODG","SID-ARCHID","SID-DSI","SID-FNGE","SID-OT-POL","SID-PILOTAG","SID-USAGRH","SIG-3D","SIG-ALTERNA","SIG-BDTOPO","SIG-CAO-DAO","SIG-DON-PDI","SIG-DONNEES","SIG-ORTHO","SIG-PLATGEO","SIG-STRUCTU","SIG-TOURNEE","SIG-WEB-PDI","STAT-CREDOC"]}

But I've still get an error with getJSON :s

Comment: I have no idea where the `"clean:` part comes from as its not what would be produced by the code I suggested

Comment: when I said clean, I mean my result is okay

{"data":["DEV-SID","ENTREPOTDUI","HYDROGEOL","MES-TEMPS","ME‌​T-ENTREPO","MIG-BO\/‌​XI","SID-AMODG","SID‌​-ARCHID","SID-DSI","‌​SID-FNGE","SID-OT-PO‌​L","SID-PILOTAG","SI‌​D-USAGRH","SIG-3D","‌​SIG-ALTERNA","SIG-BD‌​TOPO","SIG-CAO-DAO",‌​"SIG-DON-PDI","SIG-D‌​ONNEES","SIG-ORTHO",‌​"SIG-PLATGEO","SIG-S‌​TRUCTU","SIG-TOURNEE‌​","SIG-WEB-PDI","STA‌​T-CREDOC"]}

Comment: For my getJSON the error message is :

SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

return window.JSON.parse( data );

Comment: I gave up getJSON & try by using ajax.